# Cache Fallback HTTP Requests

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out the sequence to a Service I started building. What I would like to do is load cache from a Promise-based storage provider, then start an observable with that cache. Once the HTTP request resolves, I then want to replace the old cache with the new response.

I'm having a really hard time figuring out this process and would appreciate any help.

**PSEUDOCODE**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import rxjs/add/operators/map;
import rxjs/add/operators/startWith;
import {Storage} from "@ionic/storage";

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    private _cache = {};

    constructor(public http: Http; public storage: Storage){}

    public getCache(): Promise<any> {
        return this.storage.get('storageKey');
    }

    public setCache(val: any): Promise<any> {
        return this.storage.set('storageKey', val);
    }

    public getData(): Observable<any> {
        // Step 1: Get cache.
        this.getCache().then(cache => this._cache = cache);

        // Step 2: Make HTTP request.
        return this.http.get('endpoint')
        // Step 3: Set data mapping
           .map(res => this.normalize(res))
        // Step 4: Use resolved cache as startWith value
           .startWith(this._cache)
        // Step 5: Set cache to response body.
           .do(result => this.setCache(result).then(() => console.log('I resolved'));    
    }

    private normalize(data: Response): any {
       // Fun data-mapping stuff here
    }
}
```

This code is meant to run on a mobile device, where the illusion of speed, plus offline capabilities are #1 priorities. By initially setting a view with old cache, the user can view what has been stored, and if the HTTP request fails (slow network, or no network), no big deal, we fallback to the cache. However, if the user is online, we should use this opportunity to replace the old cache with the new response from the HTTP request.

Thanks for any and all help, and please let me know if I need to elaborate further.

Comment: The types here don't make sense. Since you `startWith(cache)`, then `cache` must be the same type as your stream of result JSON promises. However, it also caches the _resolved_ JSON objects, which is impossible unless `cache` and `res.json()` are both `Promise<Promise<...`.

Comment: there's a mapping function I have, instead of `.map(res => res.json()`. Let me update that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood the requirement correctly,

**Edit - adjusted following discussion**

```js
getData() {

  // storage is the cache
  const cached$ = Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('data'))  

  // return an observable with first emit of cached value
  // and second emit of fetched value.
  // Use concat operator instead of merge operator to ensure cached value is emitted first,
  // although expect storage to be faster than http 
  return cached$.concat(
    this.http.get('endpoint')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .do(result => this.storage.set('data', result))
  );
}
```

---

**Edit #2 - Handling initially empty cache**

After testing in a CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/BmoJqB), I realized there's an edge-case that means we should use `merge()` instead of `concat()`. If storage is initially empty, `concat` will block because `cached$` never emits.

Additionally, need to add `distinctUntilChanged()` because if storage is initially empty, `merge` will return the first fetch twice.

You can check out the edge-case by commenting out the line that sets `'prev value'` in the CodePen.

```js
/* Solution */
const getData = () => {
  const cached$ = Observable.fromPromise(storage.get('data'))  

  return cached$ 
    .merge(
      http.get('endpoint')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .do(result => storage.set('data', result))
    )
    .distinctUntilChanged()
}
/* Test solution */
storage.set('data', 'prev value')  // initial cache value
setTimeout( () => { getData().subscribe(value => console.log('call1', value)) }, 200)
setTimeout( () => { getData().subscribe(value => console.log('call2', value)) }, 300)
setTimeout( () => { getData().subscribe(value => console.log('call3', value)) }, 400)
```

Comment: Will this wait until the promises are resolved to continue?

Comment: @EHorodyski Are you trying to delay the HTTP request until after the cached promise has resolved? What happens if `getData` is called much more often than the requests can complete?

Comment: @concat -- I apologize, I was at my wits end last night and probably didn't explain it well enough. I'm trying to set the first stream object to what comes from the cached promise, then do the HTTP request. This is on a phone, so I'm looking to load the cache first to show the user, then make the request, then replace the cache. If the HTTP call fails, it fails, which is OK because there is some kind of cache (or empty object) coming from device storage.

Comment: Since the question has an Angular tag, I'm assuming the http.get returns an observable not a promise. `storage.get` is a promise, so added conversion. @EHorodyski, yes the main observable will only emit resolved values.

Comment: @EHorodyski, nice design, by the way.

Comment: @RichardMatsen -- Thank you! I haven't been able to test it yet, and probably won't for a while (higher priority stuff came up) but I believe it so I marked it as true. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RichardMatsen -- It works lovely! Any ideas on how I can improve my performance on my `catch` clause (see my answer). Instead of making another call, I'd like to ideally just not update the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Use concat to ensure the order ?

```
const cache = Rx.Observable.of('cache value');
const http = function(){

  return Rx.Observable.of('http value');
                        };
var storage={}
storage.set=function(value){
 return Rx.Observable.of('set value: '+value);
}
const example = cache.concat(http().flatMap(storage.set));
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log('sub:',val));`
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/hajobezuna/edit?js,console

Comment: The issue is the storage service is promise-based, not Observable based. That's what is throwing me off big time.

Comment: Use observable.fromPromise(yourPromise)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from **Richard Matsen**, this is the final result I came to. I added a `catch` clause, which might be a bit superfluous, but using Ionic on the web, you will get their debug screen, so that's why it's in there. Can the `catch` be improved so that the `do` doesn't run or something?

```
public getFeed(source: SocialSource): Observable<any> {
    const cached$ = Observable.fromPromise(this._storage.get(`${StorageKeys.Cache.SocialFeeds}.${source}`));
    const fetch$ = this._http.get(`${Configuration.ENDPOINT_SOCIAL}${source}`)
        .map(res => this.normalizeFacebook(res))
        .catch(e => cached$)
        .do(result => this._storage.set(`${StorageKeys.Cache.SocialFeeds}.${source}`, result));
    return cached$.concat(fetch$);
}
```